# What is the difference between SYN cookie, SYN cache, and SYN proxy?

Tags: firewalls, attack-prevention, ddos

I am trying to understand some techniques regarding SYN flood prevention and there are three terms I couldn't find a clear explanation of.

The terms that are confusing me are:

1. SYN Proxy
2. SYN Cache
3. SYN Cooke

What do these mean and what is the different between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syn-proxy is a propriatary protocol. An appliance will proxy any TCP request but will only forward it to the server if the three way handshake is completely established.

For SYN-Cache and SYN-Cookie refer to the following excerpt from [Cisco](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac123/ac147/archived_issues/ipj_9-4/syn_flooding_attacks.html):

> SYN Caches: Two end-host defenses, called SYN caches and SYN cookies
>   (described later), operate by reducing the amount of state allocated
>   initially for a TCB generated by a received SYN, and putting off
>   instantiating the full state [8]. In a host that uses a SYN cache, a
>   hash table with a limited amount of space in each hash bucket is used
>   to store a subset of the data that would normally go into an allocated
>   TCB. If and when a handshake completing ACK is received, this data can
>   be moved into a full TCB; otherwise the oldest bucket at a particular
>   hash value can be reaped when needed. In Lemon's FreeBSD example [8],
>   the SYN cache entry for a half connection is 160 bytes, versus 736
>   bytes for a full TCB, and 15359 entries in the SYN cache are
>   supported.
>
> The SYN cache data structure is robust to attackers attempting to
>   overflow its buckets because it uses the initiator's local port number
>   and some secret bits in the hash value. Because stacks are a more
>   effective data structure to search than a simple linked list, stacks
>   that use a SYN cache can have improved speed, even when not under
>   attack. Under Lemon's tests, during an active attack a host using a
>   SYN cache was able to establish legitimate connections with only about
>   a 15-percent increase in latency.
>
> SYN Cookies: In contrast to the SYN cache approach, the SYN cookies
>   technique causes absolutely zero state to be generated by a received
>   SYN. Instead, the most basic data comprising the connection state is
>   compressed into the bits of the sequence number used in the SYN-ACK.
>   Since for a legitimate connection, an ACK segment will be received
>   that echoes this sequence number (actually the sequence number plus
>   one), the basic TCB data can be regenerated and a full TCB can safely
>   be instantiated by decompressing the Acknowledgement field. This
>   decompression can be effective even under heavy attack because there
>   is no storage load whatsoever on the listener, only a computational
>   load to encode data into the SYN-ACK sequence numbers. The downside is
>   that not all TCB data can fit into the 32-bit Sequence Number field,
>   so some TCP options required for high performance might be disabled.
>   Another problem is that SYN-ACKs are not retransmitted (because
>   retransmission would require state), altering the TCP synchronization
>   procedures from RFC 793.
>   The exact format of TCP SYN cookies is not an interoperability issue,
>   because they are only locally interpreted, and the format and
>   procedures for generation and validation can vary slightly among
>   implementations. Figure 5 depicts the general process of SYN cookie
>   generation and validation used by multiple implementations.
>
> To compute the SYN-ACK sequence number (that is, the TCP cookie) when
>   using TCP cookies, a host first concatenates some local secret bits, a
>   data structure that contains the IP addresses and TCP ports, the
>   initial SYN sequence number, and some index data identifying the
>   secret bits. An MD5 digest is computed over all these bytes, and some
>   bits are truncated from the hash value to be placed in the SYN-ACK
>   sequence number. Because the sequence number is about a fourth the
>   size of the full hash value, this truncation is necessary, but
>   generally at least 3 bytes worth of the hash bits are used, meaning
>   that there should still be close to a 2^24 effort required to guess a
>   valid cookie without knowing the local secret bits. In addition to the
>   hash output, some of the cookie bits indicate a lower bound on the
>   Maximum Segment Size (MSS) that the SYN contained, and the index bits
>   identifying the local secret used within the hash.
>
> To validate a SYN cookie, first the acknowledgement number in an
>   incoming ACK segment is decremented by 1 to retrieve the generated SYN
>   cookie. The valid value for the set of truncated hash bits is computed
>   based on the IP address pair, TCP port numbers, segment sequence
>   number minus one, and the value from the secret pool corresponding to
>   the index bits inside the cookie. If these computed hash bits match
>   those within the ACK segment, then a TCB is initialized and the
>   connection proceeds. The encoded MSS bound is used to set a
>   reasonable-sized MSS that is no larger than what was originally
>   advertised. This MSS is usually implemented as three bits whose code
>   points correspond to eight "commonly advertised" MSS values based on
>   typical link Maximum Transmission Units (MTUs) and header overheads.
>
> Hybrid Approaches: A hybrid approach combines two or more of the
>   single defense techniques described previously. For instance, some
>   end-host operating systems implement both a large backlog and SYN
>   cookies, but enable SYN cookies only when the amount of the backlog
>   that is occupied exceeds some threshold, allowing them to normally
>   operate without the disadvantages of SYN cookies, but also allowing
>   them to fail over to the SYN-cookie behavior and be strongly protected
>   when an attack occurs.

Comment: I disagree with SYN proxy being proprietary. At least OpenBSD's PF and Linux's iptables SYN proxy module (https://lwn.net/Articles/563151/) implement it. Far from proprietary.